# Convert indexed image colormap to uint8

Tags: matlab, casting, scaling, colormap, indexed-image

I'm trying to read colormap of an image using this code:

```
[X, map] = imread('D:\Eye.png');
```

But `map` is rescaled to `[0,1]` type `double`. How can I get the colormap in **`uint8`** range `[0,255]`?

Comment: `uint8(255*map)` or perhaps `uint8(round(255*map))`?

Comment: Thanks. just what i need

Comment: You can also use `im2uint8(map)` if you have the image processing toolbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by simply rescaling `map` and casting it to `uint8`:

```
uint8(255*map);
```

Optionally, you can round it before casting (the default rounding scheme, as above, is `floor`):

```
uint8(round(255*map));
```